# What is easiest/fastest way to clone specific repository branch on local in GIT

Tags: git, github, git-bash

What would be the easiest way to clone branch from GIT project onto local so I can easily check the code on the local machine?

Currently, I know it can be downloaded from git and extracted but that is very.... time-consuming.

I am using GIT Desktop but can also work with Git Bash. (other solutions acceptable)

Thanks,
Ilija

Comment: This command is probably what you are looking for `git clone -b <branchname> <remote-repo-url>`. Source: [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-clone-branch-how-to-clone-a-specific-branch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git clone [url]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) is the universal way to clone repositories from Git via the CLI.

There are also multiple GUIs, like GitHub Desktop, Gitkraken, SourceTree, etc.  Those can actually save you a lot of time and provide a lot of functionality out of the box so you don't have to constantly be running Git commands in your terminal.

If you work with a lot of GitHub repositories, the [gh cli tool](https://github.com/cli/cli) is a time saver as well.  It automatically adds upstream projects when you clone your forks.  Say, if I have a clone of **cli/cli** in **my-github/cli**, then running `gh repo clone cli` will clone my fork, set it as the origin, and then set **cli/cli** as the upstream automatically.